# Many-to-one custom fields - unique

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I'm using a foreign table to join 2 entities, exactly this way :
http://www.prowebdev.us/2012/07/symfnoy2-many-to-many-relation-with.html

I'd like to understand why do we need an ID as primary key in the foreign table ?

I'd rather take the couple of foreign keys as the primary keys, this way I make sure that there is no double entries for the same relation. no ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Doctrine just wants every table to have and Id field, you can however force Doctrine the check if the combination of foreign keys is unique:

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
...
/*
 * @UniqueEntity({"foreign_key1", "foreign_key2"})
 * ...
 */
class JoinTable
{
    ...
}
```